# Error SQLSTATE[HY000] [1045] Access denied for user en laravel

Tags: laravel-5

Buenas tardes compañeros.

Os expongo mi problema para ver si alguién me puede orientar de como solucionarlo.

Acabo de desplegar un proyecto desarrollado en laravel 5.8 en un servidor compartido de 1and1.

He ajustado la configuración del archivo .ENV con los datos ofrecidos por 1and1 (DB_HOST, DB_PORT, DB_DATABASE, DE_USERNAME, DB_PASSWORD) al crear la base de datos y aún así me lanza un error indicando que el usuario (Usuario indicado al crear la base de datos) no tiene permisos de acceso.

```
SQLSTATE[HY000] [1045] Access denied for user 'dbu162030'@'infong-es220.clienthosting.eu' (using password: YES) (SQL: select * from `users`...
```

He comprobado la conexión a la base de datos a través de SQLyog y me puedo conectar sin problemas a ella, pero al intentarlo en laravel no puedo.

¿Alguién tiene idea de donde proviene el problema?

Un saludo y gracias de antemano.

Comment: ¿Será que estás ejecutando un tipo de consulta para la cual no tienes permiso?, lo digo porque en el error aparece `select * from users`...

Comment: Buenas tardes, el usuario indicado es el que se autogenera cuando creas la base de datos a través del panel de 1and1. Entiendo, que este usuario debe tener permisos para llevar a cabo la conexión a la base de datos y realizar la consulta.

Comment: Hola, ¿Nadie que haya tenido un escenario parecido?

Comment: ¿Por qué no pruebas con otro tipo de consulta. A veces los usuarios tienen restricciones. Puede que en este caso no tenga permiso para consultar la tabla `users`. Prueba con una tabla de las normales.

Comment: Laravel y la base de datos ¿están en el mismo host: infong-es220.clienthosting.eu?